# how to apply sharding + replication to MySQL relational db

Tags: mysql, sharding

I wanted to know, what are the different techniques for sharding and replication that can be applied to MySQL or any other relational database?

Are there any guidelines/rules that I should be aware of?

Basically, i want to create a custom MySQl(or other relational DB) that has support for sharding and replication. Most of the sites I see explain some technology or service that takes care of sharding/replication-- I want to understand the concepts and apply them myself to a regular MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Sharding is not provided for MySQL "out of the box".

[ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com) (disclaimer: I work there) is a maker of a complete scale-out solution an "automatic sharding machine" if you like. The application or any other client tool (mysql, mysqldump, PHPMyAdmin...) connects to ScaleBase controller, it looks and feels like a MySQL, proxy to a grid of "shards", automating command routing and parallelizing cross-db queries, and merge results - you wouldn't feel any difference... Just like a result that would have come from 1 DB. ORDER, GROUP, LIMIT, agg functions supported! The routing and parallelizing is done inside the "controller" according to the command and parameters. From experience with our customers, not only had we got great performance improvements with parallel queries, we also improved maintenance, think about creating an index, adding a column to a table - these are also parallelized and run much faster. All with none or pretty minimal changes to the code.

Also - I invite you to look at my blog about the subject:  http://database-scalability.blogspot.com/.

PS - I forgot to mention, that ScaleBase also completes the solution for replication with a frontend that manages automatic failover and Read/Write splitting over replicated databases.

Hope I helped

Comment: what about backups, how can we backup and restore the db, and how much time it takes to backup / restore 1TB database?